# How to replace the last octet of a valid network address with the number 2

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed

Lets say I have a string that can be any possible/valid network address like so:

```
STR="192.168.1.0/24"
```

What I want to do is replace the last octet (in this case it's 0/24, however it can be anyting) with the number 2, however I don't know what the last octet could (do not will be print the new value, so change:

```
192.168.1.0/24
```

to:

```
192.168.1.2
```

Whatever the network address is, I want to replace the last octet with "2"

Note: it is not important to check if the string is a valid network address as all strings being tested are assumed to be valid network addresses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In terminal this worked:

```
echo "192.168.1.0/24" | sed  -n 's/0.24/2/p'
```

In script this works:

```
str="192.168.1.0/24"
newstr=$(sed  -n 's/0.24/2/p' <<<$str)
```

To replace last digit of any IP address:

```
str="192.111.12.20"
newstr=$(awk -F"." '{print $1"."$2"."$3".2"}'<<<$str)
echo $newstr
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but 192.168.1.0/24 was just an example and the string can be any possible network address. Whatever the network address is, I want to replace the last octet with "2"

Comment: It was not clear from the beginning. I updated my answer.

Comment: How to reduce last 4 digits by 2 ,  newstr=$(awk -F"." '{print $1"."$2"."$3"."$4"-2"}'<<<$str). This is returning as string 4-2

Comment: Trying to turn `myip = 192.168.0.1` into `192.168.0.1/24`. This helped! `$(awk -F"." '{print $1"."$2"."$3".1//24"}'<<<$myip)`